# Reducing Tree to a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to reduce a Tree to List but I am stuck up here.. any suggestions are appreciated..

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
treeToList :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> [a]
treeToList (Node root left right) = treeToList left ++ [root] ++   treeToList right
```

Expecting Result:

> ```
> ghci> treeToList (Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 3) 4 (Leaf 5)))
>
> [1,2,3,4,5]
> ```

Comment: In the future, posting the error message or incorrect output you get is helpful to those answering your questions.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Ord` constraint? It is not necessary, is it part of your solution or part of your assignment? `treeToList :: Tree a -> [a]` suffices.

Answer (score 6):

You have two errors:

1. Non-exhaustive pattern (for `Leaf` constructor).
2. And in the pattern for `Node` you matching `root` as a left tree value (`Tree a`) and not an `a`.

Thus the result should look like:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)

treeToList :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> [a]
treeToList (Leaf v) = [v]
treeToList (Node left root right) = treeToList left ++ [root] ++ treeToList right
```

> ```
> *Main> treeToList (Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 3) 4 (Leaf 5)))
> [1,2,3,4,5]
> ```

Comment: how can i add identity function to perform sum say, the below is my function with type:                                                       treeToList :: Tree a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b      *Main>treeToList (Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 3) 4 (Leaf 5))) id sum where sum t1 v t2 = t1+v+t2   then the output is 15

Comment: @John I have no idea why you type of function is so complex. The function with a function argument should look like: `treeToFunElem :: Tree a -> (a -> a -> b) -> b`, so the result would be of type `b`, which may or may not be the same type as `a` (for example, tree of integers and taking square roots of them with convert to double).

Answer (score 3):

Riffing on m0nhawk's absolutely correct answer, I'd offer the following advice.  When you're writing a function that pattern matches on an algebraic data type like `Tree`, start by writing a template of how the function will be structured.  In this case, given the type definition:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

...and this function signature:

```
treeToList :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> [a]
```

...you can start by writing a template like this one, which is just expanding out the two alternatives of the `Tree` type and their components:

```
treeToList (Leaf value) = _
treeToList (Node left value right) = _
```

Read the `_` (underscores) as "blanks" to fill in later.  This is actually valid syntax in recent GHC versions, called a "hole" so the compiler will remind you that you need to fill it in.

By writing out a template like this and making sure you're covering all of the alternatives of the type you're working with, you greatly reduce your risk of running into problem #1 that m0nhawk pointed out.